# macro arguments causing error in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define print(x){ \
                while(*x != -1){ \
                  printf("\n %d \n",*x); \
                  x++; \
                } 

void int_copy(int* ptrA, int* ptrB, int nbr)
{
    memcpy(ptrA,ptrB,nbr);
}

int main()
{
    int stringa[40] = {100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, -1};
    int stringb[40];

    memset(stringb, 0, sizeof(stringb));

    int *ptr;
    int *ptr1;
    int len = 0;

    ptr = stringa;
    ptr1 = stringb;

    while(*ptr != -1)
    {
        *ptr++;
        len++;
    }

    printf("\n len : %d \n",len);

    int_copy(stringa, stringb, len);

    print(ptr1)

    return 0;
}
```

I got an error while trying to execute it.

Comment: *What* error? Do you expect us to know by magic? Don't you think it's helpful to include the error message?

Comment: Sidenote: `*x++;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: error : missing declaraation or statement at the end of input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the problems others have pointed out to you I'd recommend counting the number of opening and closing braces in your macro.

```
#define print(x){ \
            while(*x != -1){ \
              printf("\n %d \n",*x); \
              x++; \
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `int_copy`, the value of `len` will be 0.

Also, the code in `int_copy` is broken, it fails to scale the number of characters to copy.

It should be:

```
void int_copy(int* ptrA, const int* ptrB, int nbr)
{
  memcpy(ptrA, ptrB, nbr * sizeof *ptrB);
}
```

Since `memcpy()` copies `char`s, you must scale up by the size of an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
void int_copy(int* ptrA,int* ptrB,int nbr){
     memcpy(ptrA,ptrB,nbr);
}
```

You determine `len` as the number of `int`s in `stringa` and pass it as `nbr`. But there in `memcpy()` it's interpreteted as the buffer lenth in bytes to be copied and so, only the first part of `stringa` is copied to `stringb` not including '-1'. Change to `memcpy(ptrA,ptrB,nbr*sizeof(int))`